# TensorFlow, how to distinguish this vector operation?

Tags: tensorflow

I defined the following code below,

```py
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf

In [2]: tf.enable_eager_execution()

In [3]: v = tf.range(1, 5+1, dtype=tf.float32)

In [4]: v.numpy()
Out[4]: array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.], dtype=float32)

In [5]: v[:, None] - v[None, :]
Out[5]:
<tf.Tensor: id=13, shape=(5, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0., -1., -2., -3., -4.],
       [ 1.,  0., -1., -2., -3.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  0., -1., -2.],
       [ 3.,  2.,  1.,  0., -1.],
       [ 4.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  0.]], dtype=float32)>

In [6]: v[None, :] - v[:, None]
Out[6]:
<tf.Tensor: id=23, shape=(5, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
       [-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-4., -3., -2., -1.,  0.]], dtype=float32)>

In [7]: v[:, None].get_shape()
Out[7]: TensorShape([Dimension(5), Dimension(1)])

In [8]: v[None, :].get_shape()
Out[8]: TensorShape([Dimension(1), Dimension(5)])
```

Why `v[:, None] - v[None, :]` outputs a `5x5` matrix? `v[:, None] - v[None, :]` and `v[None, :] - v[:, None]` are different, how to figure out their differences? It really confused me and I am not sure its output given these two expressions.